# Is it possible to make col-md-3 closer or center to each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make col-md-3 closer to each other?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Center</title>
<style>

body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

</style>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is not at the center does anyone know how to fix it?

Your help much appreciated!

Comment: `<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4">` try this, if it works , then i will define the logic.

Comment: 3 equal parts would be `col-md-4` http://www.bootply.com/WY4cWrlocI

Comment: @Sampad Although it's not the result I want, but would you like to explain it how it works? I would like to learn more! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but for this you need to override styling for Bootstrap's columns. By default Bootstrap's columns are styled as `float: left`. We need to replace `float` with `display: inline-block` then we can make them in center easily with `text-align: center`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.center-align .row {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.center-align [class*='col-md'] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container center-align">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note***: Don't forget to remove extra space that comes by making an element `inline-block`.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, to apply css to parent div. In your case div with class="row" like style="text-align:center;"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should add `col-md-offset-3` class, in your `row` `class` like this:

```css
body {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Center<title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

Answer (score 0):

**Update HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend imperdiet elit vel pretium. Donec auctor urna ut dui imperdiet ullamcorper.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```