# making the contents of div row centered in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in making my div row centered, i have 3 posts from wordpress which is equivalent to 3 columns inside the row, but it didn't centered after i add many css attributes to let it center. I am also using wordpress.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code :

```
<div class="row center-block">
<?php while ( $offerBlog->have_posts() ) : $offerBlog->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <img src="<?php the_field('offer_image') ?>">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <h4><?php the_field('offer_title') ?></h4>
                        <?php the_field('offer_description') ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
    width:15%;
    margin:0 2.5%;
    text-align: center
}
.center-block {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:center;
}
```

Comment: what about `text-align: center` inside center-block selector?

Comment: `display` does not have a `center` value. I believe you are looking for `display: block`.

Comment: any answers sir ?

Comment: @JcJohn Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347643/is-it-possible-to-make-col-md-3-closer-or-center-to-each-other/39348067#39348067) Question, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Check demo [HERE](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/BLLvEV)

CSS:

```
.center-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: nice answer.. but is it compatible with all browser? or in latest browser only?

Comment: Flexbox is very well supported, at 95.89% global support. If you disregard IE 10 and below, which Microsoft says you now can, this number is even higher.

Comment: @Jyoti Pathania very nice answer ma'am, Thank you very much.