# How to make a blank div in bootstrap with no text inside full with a bg-color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How to display 3 lines inline side by side in bootstrap? I have a serious problem in the `height` and the `width`! If I use `css` only it displays. However when I want to use bootstrap I am getting stuck.

Here the code using CSS with only one line! The same process for the remaining two lines:

```
<div style="display:inline-block ;height:2px; width:100px;border-radius:10px; background-color: blue;"
```

How to do it using bootstrap? Should I use a parent class to get `the height` and `the width`?

Comment: what type of output do you exactly want could you share that please?

Comment: yeahh something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607100/making-the-contents-of-div-row-centered-in-bootstrap

Comment: please use the below code i posted. Did that is what you want or do you want another?

Comment: What do you mean by "using bootstrap"? You're adding custom CSS, so you'll need to add it either inline (like you already have), or a separate CSS file.

Comment: No man cmon withonly bootstrap with no inline css !! only bootstrap !! If it was my purpse then , i will not post this !

Comment: use another code without css. I edited my code with only bootstrap. Please check new code.

Comment: I made something like this without any container or rows !! only bootstrap but I need to reduce the height I dont know how to control the height of my span ````<span class="px-5 py-0 bg-primary w-25 rounded-pill"></span>      
                                        <span class="px-5 py-0 bg-secondary w-25 rounded-pill mx-1"></span>
                                        <span class="px-5 py-0 bg-success w-25 rounded-pill"></span>````

Answer (score 0):

You was thinking of something like this?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center bg-secondary" style="height:200px;width:auto"></div>
```

Comment: yeahh something like this !! but i want three divs side by side I dont know how to do it with bootstrap so I have to duplicate the same thing 3 times !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="p-5 bg-danger"></div>
            <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="p-5 bg-danger"></div>
            <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="p-5 bg-danger"></div>
            <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just try to remove the p below !! any way many thanks it works !

Comment: if there is another method without using container rows and col !! it will be perfect

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then it definitely use column row and container otherwise you have to use css.